Stuck at username, password and login part of Instagram for automatic log-in with selenium ChromeDriver
So, I'm trying to automate the Instagram log-in process with Selenium in python. This is my code so far:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time, urllib.request
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from time import sleep

#setting path
Path = r"C:\Users\payal\Instagram-scraper\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/C-FLnYHpUii/")

time.sleep(5)
username=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
password=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")
username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys("xxxx")
password.send_keys("1111")
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()

sleep(50)

But, it gives me an error -
  File "C:\Users\payal\Instagram-scraper\scrape.py", line 18, in <module>
    username=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'

I tried using XPATH and full XPATH as well. But it gives me either this error -
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
or it just says it can't find the xpath. In the rare case, it does log-in, it only works once and the code breaks again which might be due to dynamic xpath. Please let me know if there's a better way to solve this.
